# Crawl specific users for search

Tags: enterprise-search, people-search, ups

I have a problem, I need to configure my SharePoint search to crawl specific users based on their job title and exclude everyone else if your Job title is anything else besides developer the crawl should skip you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you explain a bit more? What do you want to achieve? 
If you want to filter the results you could simply go with a modified query in the resultsource / webpart something like `JobTitle:Developer {searchTerm}`.

Configure Result Source
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115.aspx

Or
Customize Queries
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/02/01/how-to-customize-sharepoint-2013-search-results-using-query-rules-and-result-sources/

Comment: Yes Sir I want to filter the result  to strictly developers any person who isn't a developer show not be shown when the search results come back!

Comment: Well then the approach I described should be sufficient. I can add some ressources if you need them.

Comment: Thank you very much please send me resources that I can use!